# How to make SwiftUI LazyGrid rows set heights according to contents, independently

Tags: swiftui, grid-layout, row-height

I have an array of text items with varying amounts of text in them.
I want to display them as rows of line number and text with boxes around number and txt separately. The catch is I want the box around the number to be the same height as the box around the text.

I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70555674/how-to-make-lazyvgrid-griditems-all-the-same-height) which *almost* makes it, except every line is the same height, ie sized to the largest visible row.  I want each row to be sized according to its own text size, ie each row might be a different height.

I tried changing the lazy grid to a VStack (there's unlikely to be more than forty rows) so that the sizing wasn't limited to visible rows, but then I couldn't get height **or** width to cooperate.

Is there a way?

Comment: I wrote that answer. In order to track the rows separately, your `height` variable that is set by the `PreferenceKey` would have to be something like an array or a dictionary that has separate heights for each row. Alternatively, you could use the `VStack` and have a view struct which is your row, that sizes itself with its own preference key. Try it and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and we can try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Yrb suggests a solution (which seems to me the simplest) is to modify the answer I linked by creating a struct for the rows and then moving the height calculating extension to extend *that* struct rather than the entire view.

This beautifully calculates the height of each row independently of the others.